# Python module 'modules' has no attribute 'millis'

Tags: python, python-3.x

Completely new to Python, I have installed the latest stock version, updated PIP and tried to run a script been given to import data from API (person provided says works for them), when tried to run I have installed each library as required.

```
 import json
 import pandas as pd
 from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
 import requests
 import modules
 from requests_oauthlib import OAuth1
 from datetime import datetime
```

this is main header, I am now getting error AttributeError: module 'modules' has no attribute 'millis' on following line

```
 payload = {'interactive': 'true',
       "ended": 'true',
       "start": {"from": modules.millis(2019,4,21,0,0),   # CHANGE HERE THE DATE
                 "to": modules.millis(2019,4,24,23,59)},  # CHANGE HERE THE DATA
       'skillIds':['1286977632']
        }
```

Any ideas.

Comment: Are you trying to use milliseconds?

Comment: What is `modules`? It's certainly not a python built in module. Unless you can share the contents of `modules` it is unlikely anyone can help.

Answer (score 0):

sorry guys I have found the fix, it was in a separate file I was not given at the time

```
 # returns the elapsed milliseconds since the start of the program
 def millis(year,month,day,hour,minute):
   dt = datetime(year,month,day,hour, minute) - start_time
   ms = (dt.days * 24 * 60 * 60 + dt.seconds) * 1000 + dt.microseconds / 1000.0
   return round(ms)
```

Comment: Strange question but I am not familiar with Python at all, I do have some familiarity with VBA and VB net Basic but also no experience of using API, If I provided the full Python code I know works excluding the client keys could someone translate to VB so I can better understand.